# Manual messages sync when coming from background?

Tags: applozic

I would like to use Applozic for my app. Especially the 1-to-1 chat feature.
But I heard that on iOS, when the app is in background and I got a push notification, the coming message is not showed because it needs a manual sync.

How do you manage it?

Thanks!

Comment: In which platform are you facing this issue is it in Android or IOS?

Comment: This is concerning iOS.

Comment: Can you send your applozic applicationKey and userId to support@applozic.com?